# how to truncate numbers maximally while avoiding duplicates?

Tags: r, string, type-conversion

I have a sorted sequence of numbers, e.g.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.0001, 3.0002, 4)
```

I want to format these as strings, keeping the output as short as possible, but avoiding duplicates. For example, with `x` an acceptable output would be:

```
sprintf("%.5g", x)
#> [1] "1"      "2"      "2.5"    "3"      "3.0001" "3.0002" "4"
```

But that would fail with:

```
y <- c(1, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.00001, 3.00002, 4)
sprintf("%.5g", y)
#> [1] "1"   "2"   "2.5" "3"   "3"   "3"   "4"
```

I'd be interested in the possible alternative solutions (there is a simple one below).

**Update**: the problem with just using `sprintf("%s", x)` as below is that sometimes, my input will be a set of very long numbers and I'd like to truncate them - *so long as* they don't become non-unique.

E.g. if I have

```
x <- c(1.00001, 2.00001)
```

My ideal output would be `"1", "2"`. But if I have

```
x <- c(1.00001, 1.00002)
```

Then I need `"1.00001", "1.00002"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did in the end. This makes numbers as precise as they need to be, but no more.

```
function (num) {
  for (digits in seq(0, 22L)) {
    res <- formatC(num, digits = digits, width = -1)
    if (anyDuplicated(res) == 0L) break
  }
  if (anyDuplicated(res) > 0L) stop(
        "Could not format breaks to avoid duplicates")

  return(res)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that if you just use `as.character(x)` it would not be what you needed. If you have:

```
x <- c(1.00001, 2.00001)
```

The result would be:

```
[1] "1.00001" "2.00001"
```

And not "1" and "2" as desired since each would be unique after being truncated.

I am not sure this is what you have in mind (see below), but hoped it might be helpful. One possibility is to count the number of values at each level after truncating, and including the non-truncated values when they are not unique.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,2.5,3,3.0001, 3.0002, 4)
)

library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(res = trunc(x)) %>%
  group_by(res) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(res = ifelse(n > 1, as.character(x), as.character(res)))

df$res
[1] "1"      "2"      "2.5"    "3"      "3.0001" "3.0002" "4"
```

**Edit**: If not interested in using `dplyr`, you could obtain the indices of values that are *not* duplicates (based on their truncated equivalents), and just truncate those. Here would be a base R alternative:

```
x = c(1,2,2.5,3,3.0001, 3.0002, 4.0001)
indx <- which(!duplicated(trunc(x)))
x[indx] <- as.character(trunc(x[indx]))
x
[1] "1"      "2"      "2.5"    "3"      "3.0001" "3.0002" "4"
```

Comment: I think the approach is right though pulling in dplyr is overkill, why not just use `anyDuplicated()`?

Comment: Thanks - I edited the solution for base R. Does this look closer to what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is just `sprintf("%s", x)` or equivalently

```
as.character(x)
> [1] "1"      "2"      "2.5"    "3"      "3.0001" "3.0002" "4"
```

though I am not sure when and how this might go wrong. It seems to work up to differences of about `1e-14` on my computer.